# Get the response headers from redirect url using node.js

Tags: node.js

**Objective:**
 Te  get the response.headers when I get the status code as 302 from redirects uri response

**Issue:**

I did a bit of googling about an issue which i'm facing at my end about the Redirect URL returning 500 rather than the expected 302. I found the npm request() can be used for redirects. However I'm not able to get the response headers as it always returns 500. But when I used the API end points manually with Postman (with interceptors turned ON) along with body and headers, I was able to get 302 redirects. This is essentially used for Automation testing for API

```
  request(
  url: 'https://blah/blah',
  client_id:'something.com.au'
  redirect_uri:'http://something' // used for mobile app and so it is OK to be have a valid url
  response_type :'code'
  scope : 'ALLAPI',
  Username : 'cxxx'
  Password : 'ccxcxc'
  headers : {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'followRedirect' : true
  }, function (error, response) {
             console.log('The response val is', response.statusCode);

   });
```

**Question:**
Not sure if npm request can do the justice or Am I using request in-correctly or should I have to use axios/follow-redirects etc.. something like that. Please advise. If anyone can provide proper directions on this, it'll be really helpful

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: If you're getting 500 errors, the server is not happy with your request (for whatever reason). You should get the requests working properly first. Also, it looks like you're passing request data as properties to `request`, where you probably want to use the `form` property).

Comment: Thanks Robertklep!!!. Yep. I've resolved that using form property.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) works for me.

```js
var needle = require('needle'),
    url = 'https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?htmlfid=GBE03831USEN&';;

needle.get(url, {follow_max: 5}, function(error, res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@all. I've resolved using form property but with using req.post() method which returned the statuscode as 302 with response headers.  Thanks all once again.